# how to create a class in vb for excel

Tags: class, excel, vba

Hello im trying to create a class in vb and when and try to instance the class the class is without any value

```
Private lat As Double
Private lon As Double

Public Property Get Longitud() As Double

Longitud = lon

End Property
Public Property Get Latitud() As Double
Latitud = lat

End Property
Public Property Let Longitud(ByVal longi As Double)

Longitud = lon

End Property

Public Property Let Latitud(ByVal lati As Double)

Latitud = lat
End Property
```

And when im trying to instance

```
Dim cord As Coordenadas
Set cord = New Coordenadas
cord.Latitud = 40.30416667
cord.Longitud = 0.22583333
```

I cant see any change in the cord

Comment: You should revisit your 'Property Let'-Procedures: What do they do? What should they be doing?

Comment: Ohh thanks I notice is a lon when the value im passing is longi!! thats my misstake tanks alex

Comment: You're welcome. If you have the solution, consider posting it as an answer to your own question. - Be prepared to see your question closed as "too localized" or even removed, though, as it may have too little significance apart from helping you to find the bug in your own code (apart from the fact that probably everyone at least once stumbled over such trivialities). (You may want to read the [FAQ] about this, too)

Comment: Ok alex :D thanks again for all the information you gave me in the last lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Let property is not allocating correctly the value you passed as argument.
It should be as follows:

```
Private lon As Double
'

Public Property Let Longitud(ByVal longi As Double)

    lon = longi

End Property
```

`Let` should assign the value to your private variable (Lon) and `Get` should retrieve the value stored inside that variable.

Just as an addition, it will help you a lot if you give your private properties a special suffix.  For example pLon and pLat.  This way is easier for you to identify the variables from the arguments and properties.